# agregar columnas dinamicamente con ngx-datatable?

Tags: javascript, html, array, angular, datatable

estoy trabajando con angular,
estoy buscando una manera de agregar columnas a un ngx-datatable "dinámicamente" pero no puedo encontrar una manera. Lo que estoy tratando de lograr es apartir de algunos datos que me llegan del backend, crear checkbox y poder llenar la tabla con los datos que le corresponden.

el array que me llega del backend tiene este formato.

```
     row = [
      {role: "administrador", id: 1}
      {role: "operario", id: 2}
      {role: "visitante", id: 3}
     ]
```

lo que logre fue lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi archivo grid.html

```
    <form appParentFormSubmit appChildFormSubmit [formGroup]="formGroup" 
    *ngIf="formField.name">

    <ngx-datatable #myTable class="material" style="width: 100%" [rows]="rows" 
    [columnMode]="ColumnMode.force"
    [headerHeight]="50" [footerHeight]="50" [rowHeight]="50" [limit]="5" 
    [selected]="selected"
    [selectionType]="SelectionType.checkbox" [selectAllRowsOnPage]="false" 
    [displayCheck]="displayCheck"
    (activate)="onActivate($event)" (select)="onSelect($event)" [scrollbarV]="false" 
    (page)="onPage($event)"
   [loadingIndicator]="loadingIndicator" [reorderable]="reorderable">

   <ngx-datatable-column [width]="60" [sortable]="false" [canAutoResize]="false" 
   [draggable]="false"
   [resizeable]="false" [headerCheckboxable]="true" [checkboxable]="true">
   </ngx-datatable-column>

   <ngx-datatable-column *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index" [name]="col.name" 
   [flexGrow]="col.flexGrow">
   <ng-template ngx-datatable-header-template>
   {{ col.name }}
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
   {{ col.prop }}
   </ng-template>
   </ngx-datatable-column>

   <ngx-datatable-column [width]="80" [resizeable]="true" [sortable]="true" 
   [draggable]="true" [canAutoResize]="false"
   [frozenLeft]="false" [checkboxable]="true" [headerCheckboxable]="true" >

   </ngx-datatable-column>

  <ngx-datatable-column [width]="20" [resizeable]="true" [sortable]="true" 
  [draggable]="true" [canAutoResize]="false"
   [frozenLeft]="false">
   <ng-template let-row="row" let-expanded="expanded" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" [class.datatable-icon-right]="!expanded" 
    [class.datatable-icon-down]="expanded"
       title="Expand/Collapse Row" (click)="toggleExpandRow(row)">
     </a>
    </ng-template>
   </ngx-datatable-column>
 
   </ngx-datatable>
  </form>
```

Mi archivo generico grid.ts

```
      import { Component, OnInit, Input, ApplicationRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, 
      Injector, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
      import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
      import { ColumnMode,SelectionType } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';
      import { FormField } from '../../generic-input/models/form-field.model';

      @Component({
      selector: 'app-grid-row-detail',
      templateUrl: './grid-row-detail.component.html',
      })
      export class GridRowDetail<T> implements OnInit {
      @Input()
      formField: FormField<T> = new FormField();
      @Input()
      formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
      @Input()
      required = false;
      @Input()
      classes: string;

      @ViewChild("myTable", { static: false }) table: any;
      public rows = [];

      public timeout: any;

      public selected = [];

      public columns = [];

      public ColumnMode = ColumnMode;

      public SelectionType = SelectionType;
  
      public resultColumns: any[] = [];

      public type = SelectionType;
      constructor() {
      }

      ngOnInit() {
      this.generateColumns();
      this.rows = this.formField.componentGridExpandable.row;
      this.columns = this.formField.componentGridExpandable.columns;

       }

       onSelect({ selected }) {
       console.log('Select Event', selected, this.selected);
       this.selected.splice(0, this.selected.length);
       this.selected.push(...selected);
       }

       onActivate(event) {
       console.log('Evento activado', event);
        }


        generateColumns() {
        this.formField.componentGridExpandable.row.forEach((item) => {

          this.formField.componentGridExpandable.columns.push({
           prop: item.role,
          })
          })
          console.log(this.formField.componentGridExpandable.columns);
   
         }
        }
```

El archivo en el cual armo la grilla add.grid.ts

```
          @Component({
          selector: 'app-add-update',
          templateUrl: './add-update.component.html',
            })
           export class AddUpdateComponent extends DefaultAddUpdateComponent<User> 
         implements OnInit 
          {
          public columns;
          public row;
          public id;

          formFields: FormField<User & { 'new-password'?: string, 'other-password'?: 
           string }>[] 
         = [
           {
           name: 'rols',
          label: 'roles',
           placeholder: 'search_by_id_number',
          type: 'componentGridExpandable',
          componentGridExpandable: {
          row:[

           ],
           columns: [
           {
           name: "Roles",
            prop: "role",
          },
          {
           name: "ID",
           prop: "id",
          }
          ],
           }
           },
            ];


          @ViewChild('genericForm', { read: false, static: false }) genericForm: 
          GenericFormComponent<User>;

           constructor(
           public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
            public router: Router,
          public gridDataService: GridEventsService,
          public alertService: AlertService,
         public modalOutletService: ModalOutletService,
         private userService: UserService,
         private extrasService: ExtrasService,
         ) {
        super(activatedRoute, router, gridDataService, alertService, 
         modalOutletService);
        this.initVars();
          }

         ngOnInit() {
        super.ngOnInit();
         }

        async initVars() {
         const rolsType = (await this.extrasService.getRoles());
         const formFieldsData = this.formFields
        const datosversianda = [];
        const pushear = [];
       formFieldsData.map(function (dataCol) {
       if (dataCol.type === 'componentGridExpandable') {
       rolsType.map(item2 => {
      pushear.push({ role: item2.role, id: item2.id, permissions: item2.permissions 
      })
      })
     dataCol.componentGridExpandable.row = pushear
    }
    })
    }

    }
```

Cualquier ayuda se los agradezco, desde ya muchas gracias.